# In QGIS 2.12 processing R scripts fails (plots remain blank) due to a wrong variable name - Is there a workaround?

Tags: r, qgis-processing

I am trying to execute r scripts in 2.12. All of them fail. Plots remain blank.

It seems that the variable "Layer[[Field]]" returns NULL: E.g:

> hist(Layer[[Field]],main=paste("Histogram
>   of",Field),xlab=paste(Field))

Returns the error that x must be numeric. It seems to me that it does not work because Layer[[Field]] returns Null. In my case the variable "Field" contains the value "6_Farbcode". If I copy the whole code to the R console and replace the variable name "Field" with a number, e.g. 6 for the column of the table it works. So I guess this can be traced back to a syntax error in QGIS?:

[image: Log file of histogram funktion]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @benemoto! What about creating a new integer field which only contains the **number** from your original field? You could use an expression for this but it depends on a few things such as if all values have a single number, do they start off at the left etc. From the example you gave, you could use an expression like: `left("Field", 1)` to extract the very first character from the left-hand side.